# How to get a href link using xpath (xpath_query) from website (any url)?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, xpath

I want to fetch my social links from this url.

http://profiles.wordpress.org/mahesh901122

Profile picture of Mahesh Waghmare

```
Member Since: October 6th, 2012
Pune, Maharashtra, India
Wordpress Developer

Find me on: https://www.facebook.com/mwaghmare7
            http://profiles.google.com/101103699636703768957
```

I was try: //a[@id='user-social-media-accounts']/@href but it can't returns any url. Suggets xpath_query for google spreedsheet or other way to get these links. Any tricks for wordpress/php developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user-social-media-accounts` is the `id` of `<ul>` tag, not `<a>` tag. This XPath was able to return 3 social media urls as expected for me when tested using google spreadsheet :

```
//ul[@id='user-social-media-accounts']/li/a/@href
```

Comment: Great! It works. Have any idea to combine all links within single cell. eg.importxml(A1,"//ul[@id='user-social-media-accounts']/li/a/@href");

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way using XPath. And I don't know much about google spreadsheet functions.